# Chrome Dev Tools - Elements Panel - Context menu stopped working

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have been using the Elements page to edit html. It was all working fine; right-click brings up the full context menu then I can edit the html.

Now when I right-click, I only get 'Services' (an OS X item).

This only occurs on the site I am editing. If I do the same thing on any other site, I am able to edit the html.

Any ideas why this would be or how to fix it?

Edit - It started working. All I did was switch between pages and keep closing and opening the dev tools. No idea what really fixed it.

Comment: I know you solved it on your end, but can you please verify if [@Benjamin's scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71574207/12015105) applies to your Chrome installation as well? I just reported it as a workaround to the [Chromium project's issues](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1331197#c4).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue and was able to remove it by changing the scaling of the developer tools with CMD + "+" and CMD + "-". It seems as if the context menu is inaccessible below certain font sizes.

Comment: Indeed, the context menu depends on the DevTools zoom level, and its high enough value enables the menu.

Comment: Thanks for this. I had blamed and cursed the whole universe, uninstalled extensions and whatnot before I found this question. I [just reported the zoom level as being related to this problem in Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1331197#c4) and linked this SO question.

Answer (score 0):

Someone reported this [issue](https://github.com/auchenberg/chrome-devtools-app/issues/6) once in the past, but it was not easy for them to replicate it. If you find out how you got the issue, consider commenting on the issue so that it gets re-opened. Otherwise, if it's just a fluke, then I guess leave it as that.